# Auto layout with UIScrollView using .xib

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiscrollview, autolayout, xib

I have enabled auto layout in my .xib but unfortunately, scroll view does not scroll anymore.

[image]

**Constraints on my view:**

[image]

**Constraints on my scrollView:**

[image]

**Constraints on my contentView:**

[image]

What I am missing here. Thanks for your help.

Comment: Your contentView height should be equal to the sum of all children inside it rather than just the height of _View_.

Answer (score 0):

Try to set contentSize like

```
 sview.contentSize = CGSizeMake(ScreenWidth, 1000);
```

Comment: Its work for me. I forget to set scrollView Content Size. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The contentsize of the scrollView should be determined by the contentView's needed height automatically. Make sure the subviews of contentView have all vertical constraints so the contentView will adapt in height.

In your case you've set contentView.height == view.height. It should work if you remove this constraint and make sure contentView does expand(height) according to it's subviews.

Answer (score 0):

> Add one more constraint of Contentview height >= Current height 
>   This will do the trick

Answer (score -2):

You can refer this. It is a nice tutorial for [Autolayout with ScrollView](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=UnQsFlMGDsI).

Comment: This tutorial is for storyboard and i mentioned in my question that I am using .xib file. Thanks

Comment: I think you can do same in your .xib not sure but you can try it.